# JavaCard sending APDU returns 67 00 Wrong Length

Tags: javacard, apdu

I have a Javacard with IC - SLC32PDL348, Javacard Version 3.0.4, Cosmofly V.6.0. From an ACR128U-C1 card reader I can read/write to it. But from embedded I can only get RATS correctly but after RATS, every APDU that I send receives 67 00 : Wrong Length response. I can't step to transparent mode. Can anyone help with it? I tried to wrap it as TPDU as well ..

```
    memcpy(APDU.pSendBuffer,"\x00\xA4\x04\x00\x06\xC2\x00\x00\xAB\x01\x01",11); 
    APDU.SendLength = 11;       
    result = CPU_APDU(&APDU);       
    if(result != FM175XX_SUCCESS)
```

Thanx.

Comment: Could you try `"\x00\xA4\x04\x0C\x06\xC2\x00\x00\xAB\x01\x01"`?

Comment: That worked, could you please tell what am I missing here? PC side works well with the first form where embedded works only with yours, how's that possible? Thank you.

Comment: The `P2 = 0x0C` specifies that no information is to be returned. So either this information is not available or your response buffer is configured incorrectly. Note that without response, it is also an ISO type 3 command rather than a type 4 command. This is more compatible with T=0 protocol where you'd require a `GET RESPONSE` to retrieve data after a type 4 command. Unfortunately you still have to find out which one of these 3 is applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll proceed that way.

Comment: (the third one is that only the command that doesn't return data is available, I reread and counted to two, so something was wrong :) )

Comment: Oh, and try the command with an additional 0x00 byte attached to the end, as Le byte. Sorry, should have mentioned that first.